# Plugin Development: Dynamically change post title (the_title()) from a plugin, without changing database title

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am developing a custom plugin that needs to change the post title dynamically (NOT the "title" tag for the head) without using a page template.

I want the end user of the plugin to be able to use their own theme templates, which will already output the title, usually in an h1 tag, but I don't know where and how for sure, because it is not my theme.

I will need to just change the output on the frontend, not in the database. I want to change it based on whether a url's query string matches certain values, or whether the frontend user is logged in or not. I know how to do this from a custom template, but I want to do this from a template the user already has selected.

I noticed that if I filter the_title(), it changes it everywhere in the admin dashboard and in the frontend navigation menus, which is what I don't want, I just want to change where it is outputted in the user's page template (usually in an h1 tag).... does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: Use the [is_admin()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) function to check whether the user is in the admin area or not before changing the title (eg. `if ( ! is_admin() ) { /* Do your thing */ }`).

Comment: @cabrerahector, even if !is_admin returns true, when I filter the title, it filters it in the navigation menu on the frontend also, not just in the template's h1 tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use the_title filter, which would have influence only on front-end, this doesn't change record in Database. Your code would be something like this:
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_text_to_post_title' );

```
function add_text_to_page_title( $title ) {
    if( is_post() )
        $title = 'Your text: '. $title;

    return $title;
}
```

Comment: the_title filter does change it in the dashboard, but you can circumvent this by first checking if is_admin() or not. But even still, this changes the title everywhere on the frontend... i.e. navigation menus, not just in the h1 tag, like my question asked.

Comment: @Jeremy In this case i suggest to use js, for example you can do something like: var = `$('h1').text(); $('h1').text('your text' + var);`